# Gatsby - Build exceeded maximum allowed runtime

Tags: deployment, netlify

I'm looking for a solution to the issue with netlify deploy. Everything was working fine until I see `Build exceeded maximum allowed runtime` at the very end of the deploy logs. It's a Gatsby Site with a Contentful CMS. 2-3 days back deployment was working fine, I don't know what the issue is. Please, help me with the issue.

```
7:18:32 PM: Build ready to start
7:18:34 PM: build-image version: 0e2f4c52031ab562db66aec633308326e3b108d0 (focal)
7:18:34 PM: build-image tag: focal
7:18:34 PM: buildbot version: ed990b4b6588208e959ba45b6b7b05738f8b6004
7:18:34 PM: Fetching cached dependencies
7:18:34 PM: Failed to fetch cache, continuing with build
7:18:34 PM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
7:18:35 PM: No cached dependencies found. Cloning fresh repo
7:18:35 PM: git clone https://github.com/pbit0x/Flow-It-All
7:18:36 PM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/master
7:18:36 PM: Parsing package.json dependencies
7:18:38 PM: Starting build script
7:18:38 PM: Installing dependencies
7:18:38 PM: Python version set to 2.7
7:18:38 PM: v16.15.1 is already installed.
7:18:39 PM: Now using node v16.15.1 (npm v8.11.0)
7:18:39 PM: Started restoring cached build plugins
7:18:39 PM: Finished restoring cached build plugins
7:18:39 PM: Attempting ruby version 2.7.2, read from environment
7:18:40 PM: Using ruby version 2.7.2
7:18:40 PM: Using PHP version 8.0
7:18:40 PM: Started restoring cached yarn cache
7:18:40 PM: Finished restoring cached yarn cache
7:18:41 PM: No yarn workspaces detected
7:18:41 PM: Started restoring cached node modules
7:18:41 PM: Finished restoring cached node modules
7:18:41 PM: Installing NPM modules using Yarn version 1.22.10
7:18:41 PM: npm WARN config tmp This setting is no longer used.  npm stores temporary files in a special
7:18:41 PM: npm WARN config location in the cache, and they are managed by
7:18:41 PM: npm WARN config     [`cacache`](http://npm.im/cacache).
7:18:42 PM: yarn install v1.22.10
7:18:42 PM: [1/4] Resolving packages...
7:18:42 PM: [2/4] Fetching packages...
7:19:19 PM: info fsevents@2.3.2: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
7:19:19 PM: info "fsevents@2.3.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
7:19:19 PM: info @lmdb/lmdb-darwin-arm64@2.5.2: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
7:19:19 PM: info "@lmdb/lmdb-darwin-arm64@2.5.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
7:19:19 PM: info @lmdb/lmdb-darwin-arm64@2.5.2: The CPU architecture "x64" is incompatible with this module.
7:19:19 PM: info @lmdb/lmdb-darwin-x64@2.5.2: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
7:19:19 PM: info "@lmdb/lmdb-darwin-x64@2.5.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
7:19:19 PM: info @lmdb/lmdb-linux-arm@2.5.2: The CPU architecture "x64" is incompatible with this module.
7:19:19 PM: info "@lmdb/lmdb-linux-arm@2.5.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
7:19:19 PM: info @lmdb/lmdb-linux-arm64@2.5.2: The CPU architecture "x64" is incompatible with this module.
7:19:19 PM: info "@lmdb/lmdb-linux-arm64@2.5.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
7:19:19 PM: info @lmdb/lmdb-win32-x64@2.5.2: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
7:19:19 PM: info "@lmdb/lmdb-win32-x64@2.5.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
7:19:19 PM: info lmdb-darwin-arm64@2.3.10: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
7:19:19 PM: info "lmdb-darwin-arm64@2.3.10" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
7:19:19 PM: info lmdb-darwin-arm64@2.3.10: The CPU architecture "x64" is incompatible with this module.
7:19:19 PM: info lmdb-darwin-x64@2.3.10: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
7:19:19 PM: info "lmdb-darwin-x64@2.3.10" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
7:19:19 PM: info lmdb-linux-arm@2.3.10: The CPU architecture "x64" is incompatible with this module.
7:19:19 PM: info "lmdb-linux-arm@2.3.10" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
7:19:19 PM: info lmdb-linux-arm64@2.3.10: The CPU architecture "x64" is incompatible with this module.
7:19:19 PM: info "lmdb-linux-arm64@2.3.10" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
7:19:19 PM: info lmdb-win32-x64@2.3.10: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
7:19:19 PM: info "lmdb-win32-x64@2.3.10" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
7:19:19 PM: info @msgpackr-extract/msgpackr-extract-darwin-arm64@2.0.2: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
7:19:19 PM: info "@msgpackr-extract/msgpackr-extract-darwin-arm64@2.0.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
7:19:19 PM: info @msgpackr-extract/msgpackr-extract-darwin-arm64@2.0.2: The CPU architecture "x64" is incompatible with this module.
7:19:19 PM: info @msgpackr-extract/msgpackr-extract-darwin-x64@2.0.2: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
7:19:19 PM: info "@msgpackr-extract/msgpackr-extract-darwin-x64@2.0.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
7:19:19 PM: info @msgpackr-extract/msgpackr-extract-linux-arm@2.0.2: The CPU architecture "x64" is incompatible with this module.
7:19:19 PM: info "@msgpackr-extract/msgpackr-extract-linux-arm@2.0.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
7:19:19 PM: info @msgpackr-extract/msgpackr-extract-linux-arm64@2.0.2: The CPU architecture "x64" is incompatible with this module.
7:19:19 PM: info "@msgpackr-extract/msgpackr-extract-linux-arm64@2.0.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
7:19:19 PM: info @msgpackr-extract/msgpackr-extract-win32-x64@2.0.2: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
7:19:19 PM: info "@msgpackr-extract/msgpackr-extract-win32-x64@2.0.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
7:19:19 PM: [3/4] Linking dependencies...
7:19:19 PM: warning "@emotion/react > @emotion/babel-plugin@11.9.2" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0".
7:19:19 PM: warning "@emotion/react > @emotion/babel-plugin > @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx@7.18.6" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
7:19:19 PM: warning "gatsby > eslint-config-react-app@6.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "babel-eslint@^10.0.0".
7:19:19 PM: warning "gatsby > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.21.0" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
7:19:19 PM: warning "gatsby > gatsby-parcel-config > @gatsbyjs/parcel-namer-relative-to-cwd@1.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@parcel/namer-default@2.5.0".
7:19:19 PM: warning "gatsby > react-dev-utils > fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@6.5.2" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>= 2.7".
7:19:19 PM: warning "gatsby > eslint-plugin-graphql > graphql-config > @endemolshinegroup/cosmiconfig-typescript-loader > ts-node@9.1.1" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.7".
7:19:19 PM: warning " > gatsby-plugin-image@2.17.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.12.3".
7:19:19 PM: warning "gatsby-plugin-netlify > webpack-assets-manifest@5.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^5.2.0".
7:19:19 PM: warning " > gatsby-source-contentful@7.15.0" has unmet peer dependency "sharp@^0.30.1".
7:19:19 PM: warning " > react-share@4.4.0" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^16.3.0 || ^17".
7:19:19 PM: warning " > styled-components@5.3.5" has unmet peer dependency "react-is@>= 16.8.0".
7:19:41 PM: [4/4] Building fresh packages...
7:19:46 PM: Done in 64.31s.
7:19:46 PM: NPM modules installed using Yarn
7:19:46 PM: Started restoring cached go cache
7:19:46 PM: Finished restoring cached go cache
7:19:46 PM: Installing Go version 1.17 (requested 1.17)
7:19:52 PM: unset GOOS;
7:19:52 PM: unset GOARCH;
7:19:52 PM: export GOROOT='/opt/buildhome/.gimme/versions/go1.17.linux.amd64';
7:19:52 PM: export PATH="/opt/buildhome/.gimme/versions/go1.17.linux.amd64/bin:${PATH}";
7:19:52 PM: go version >&2;
7:19:52 PM: export GIMME_ENV="/opt/buildhome/.gimme/env/go1.17.linux.amd64.env"
7:19:52 PM: go version go1.17 linux/amd64
7:19:52 PM: Installing missing commands
7:19:52 PM: Verify run directory
7:19:53 PM: ​
7:19:53 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
7:19:53 PM:   Netlify Build                                                 
7:19:53 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
7:19:53 PM: ​
7:19:53 PM: ❯ Version
7:19:53 PM:   @netlify/build 27.3.3
7:19:53 PM: ​
7:19:53 PM: ❯ Flags
7:19:53 PM:   baseRelDir: true
7:19:53 PM:   buildId: 62c6eb389ed7b80008bd0cda
7:19:53 PM:   deployId: 62c6eb389ed7b80008bd0cdc
7:19:53 PM: ​
7:19:53 PM: ❯ Current directory
7:19:53 PM:   /opt/build/repo
7:19:53 PM: ​
7:19:53 PM: ❯ Config file
7:19:53 PM:   No config file was defined: using default values.
7:19:53 PM: ​
7:19:53 PM: ❯ Context
7:19:53 PM:   production
7:19:53 PM: ​
7:19:53 PM: ❯ Installing plugins
7:19:53 PM:    - @netlify/plugin-gatsby@3.2.4
7:20:05 PM: ​
7:20:05 PM: ❯ Loading plugins
7:20:05 PM:    - @netlify/plugin-gatsby@3.2.4 from Netlify app
7:20:07 PM: ​
7:20:07 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
7:20:07 PM:   1. @netlify/plugin-gatsby (onPreBuild event)                  
7:20:07 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
7:20:07 PM: ​
7:20:07 PM: No Gatsby cache found. Building fresh.
7:20:07 PM: ​
7:20:07 PM: (@netlify/plugin-gatsby onPreBuild completed in 18ms)
7:20:07 PM: ​
7:20:07 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
7:20:07 PM:   2. Build command from Netlify app                             
7:20:07 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
7:20:07 PM: ​
7:20:07 PM: $ yarn build
7:20:07 PM: yarn run v1.22.10
7:20:07 PM: $ gatsby build
7:20:10 PM: success compile gatsby files - 0.931s
7:20:10 PM: success load gatsby config - 0.025s
7:20:11 PM: success load plugins - 0.748s
7:20:11 PM: success onPreInit - 0.006s
7:20:11 PM: success initialize cache - 0.066s
7:20:11 PM: success copy gatsby files - 0.112s
7:20:11 PM: success Compiling Gatsby Functions - 0.200s
7:20:11 PM: success onPreBootstrap - 0.210s
7:20:11 PM: success createSchemaCustomization - 0.113s
7:20:12 PM: success Contentful: Sync all items - 0.166s - 47/47 283.19/s
7:20:12 PM: success Contentful: Fetch data - 0.442s
7:20:12 PM: info Contentful: 24 new entries
7:20:12 PM: info Contentful: 9 updated entries
7:20:12 PM: info Contentful: 0 deleted entries
7:20:12 PM: info Contentful: 0 cached entries
7:20:12 PM: info Contentful: 14 new assets
7:20:12 PM: info Contentful: 0 updated assets
7:20:12 PM: info Contentful: 0 cached assets
7:20:12 PM: info Contentful: 0 deleted assets
7:20:12 PM: info Creating 1 Contentful Home nodes
7:20:12 PM: info Creating 3 Contentful Teaser Component nodes
7:20:12 PM: info Creating 2 Contentful Article Template nodes
7:20:12 PM: info Creating 1 Contentful FAQ nodes
7:20:12 PM: info Creating 3 Contentful FAQ Question Template nodes
7:20:12 PM: info Creating 4 Contentful FAQ Question Answer Section nodes
7:20:12 PM: info Creating 1 Contentful App Status Page nodes
7:20:12 PM: info Creating 6 Contentful Services Status nodes
7:20:12 PM: info Creating 1 Contentful Footer nodes
7:20:12 PM: info Creating 1 Contentful Footer Queries Section nodes
7:20:12 PM: info Creating 1 Contentful Our Best Feature Section nodes
7:20:12 PM: info Creating 6 Contentful Feature nodes
7:20:12 PM: info Creating 1 Contentful Topics nodes
7:20:12 PM: info Creating 1 Contentful Stay In Touch nodes
7:20:12 PM: info Creating 1 Contentful Single Topic nodes
7:20:12 PM: info Creating 14 Contentful asset nodes
7:20:12 PM: success Contentful: Create nodes - 0.141s
7:20:12 PM: success Contentful: Process data - 0.173s
7:20:12 PM: success Checking for changed pages - 0.000s
7:20:12 PM: success source and transform nodes - 0.807s
7:20:13 PM: info Writing GraphQL type definitions to /opt/build/repo/.cache/schema.gql
7:20:15 PM: success building schema - 2.997s
7:20:15 PM: success createPages - 0.084s
7:20:15 PM: success createPagesStatefully - 0.203s
7:20:15 PM: info Total nodes: 107, SitePage nodes: 7 (use --verbose for breakdown)
7:20:15 PM: success Checking for changed pages - 0.000s
7:20:15 PM: success onPreExtractQueries - 0.000s
7:20:21 PM: success extract queries from components - 5.518s
7:20:21 PM: success write out redirect data - 0.002s
7:20:21 PM: success onPostBootstrap - 0.001s
7:20:21 PM: info bootstrap finished - 14.241s
7:20:21 PM: success write out requires - 0.005s
7:20:58 PM: success Building production JavaScript and CSS bundles - 36.481s
7:21:12 PM: <w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Skipped not serializable cache item 'mini-css-extract-plugin /opt/build/repo/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[10].oneOf[1].use[1]!/opt/build/repo/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[10].oneOf[1].use[2]!/opt/build/repo/src/assets/css/layout.css|0|Compilation/modules|/opt/build/repo/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[10].oneOf[1].use[1]!/opt/build/repo/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[10].oneOf[1].use[2]!/opt/build/repo/src/assets/css/layout.css': No serializer registered for Warning
7:21:12 PM: <w> while serializing webpack/lib/cache/PackFileCacheStrategy.PackContentItems -> webpack/lib/NormalModule -> Array { 1 items } -> webpack/lib/ModuleWarning -> Warning
7:21:14 PM: success Building HTML renderer - 16.204s
7:21:14 PM: success Execute page configs - 0.022s
7:21:14 PM: success Caching Webpack compilations - 0.000s
7:21:23 PM: success run queries in workers - 9.090s - 8/8 0.88/s
7:21:23 PM: success Merge worker state - 0.001s
7:21:23 PM: success Rewriting compilation hashes - 0.004s
7:21:23 PM: success Writing page-data.json files to public directory - 0.004s - 7/7 1745.23/s
7:54:32 PM: Build exceeded maximum allowed runtime
```

Comment: This started happening to me July 5th or 6th. My last successful build at Netlify as July 4. Reported to Netlify [here](https://answers.netlify.com/t/gatsby-site-build-timed-out/70872).

Comment: I'm getting the exact same issue, at the exact same step `writing page-data.json` Did you have any luck resolving this issue? Like yourself, this just started out of nowhere, whereas everything was working fine a few days prior.

Comment: same issue here - I upgrade React to v18 and started seeing "Build exceeded maximum allowed runtime"  Any luck resolving the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Just like the error says, the build took more than the maximum allowed time. Netlify allows 15 min as the default time for builds to finish. Once you're over this limit, the builds would most likely fail.

You can contact Netlify Support to get the limit raised. It's usually not chargeable.

Comment: As I mentioned 2 days back, it was working fine so netlify default build time is enough now as well. I think the issue is something else, I am trying to run the gatsby build command locally as well `success Writing page-data.json files to public directory - 0.022s - 7/7 322.78/s
[  ]   0.001 s 0/7 0% Building static HTML for pages` at this step it seems it stuck.

Comment: There could be multiple causes for that: 1) Something went wrong on Netlify's end and could be a temporary issue, 2) Your build process might be taking more memory than Netlify's pods might be allowing, so it might be struggling in there, 3) your code might be stuck on some step and maybe you need to trigger verbose logging.

Comment: The build time is exceeded, but notice the timestamp of the last two log enteries: `7:21:23 PM` then `7:54:32 PM`. Something is going terribly wrong in those ~30 minutes.

Comment: Exactly why I listed the three options in my previous comment